# Boolean Algebra, Proving expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I've been struggling to prove this expression literally all day please help.

A'B + A'C + B'C = A'B + B'C

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\begin{align*}
A'B+A'C+B'C&=A'B+A'(B+B')C+B'C\\
&=(A'B+A'BC)+(A'B'C+B'C)
\end{align*}$$

Now simplify the expressions in parenthesis.